# GCC suddenly stopped working? Missing dependencies?

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, mingw

NOTE THIS QUESTION IS NOT: [MinGW / gcc: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124182/mingw-gcc-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

I tried dependency walkers and it says the following dependencies are missing:

```
API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL
API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL
DCOMP.DLL
GPSVC.DLL
IESHIMS.DLL
```

I've heard not to trust dependency walker in these cases and all I know is that GCC suddenly stopped compiling a particular piece of a software. I have no idea what could have caused this. I recently repartitioned my harddive using GParted, could that be the cause? Any ideas on how to fix it? Moreover, this is very similar to a linked question, but I have not messed around with the System_Path so I have no idea what could be causing it. I already tried to reinstall GCC from packages. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It didn't "suddenly" stop doing anything. You changed a configuration on your computer.

Comment: I really don't see how this is _not_ a duplicate of the linked question. The symptoms are _exactly_ the same. If you didn't like the answer posted on it, offer a bounty to get more attention and a different answer.

Comment: That is like arguing a nose bleed and leukemia should be on the same page in a medical textbook because they have similar symptoms.

Comment: No, it's like arguing that a nose bleed and a nose bleed should be on the same page in a medical textbook because they are the same thing.