# What should I do to avoid a C++ program 0xc000007b error using VS Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have recently installed VSC on my Win10 PC.

I was trying my first Hello world program in C++.

Building the program was successful.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    cout<<"Hello world!"<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Execution of the corresponding `.exe` file gave me the error 0xc000007b.

The interesting thing is that in the past I have installed minGW. Selecting that compiler today, no error appears and I can run the `.exe` file and see `Hello world!` displayed in the Windows console.

Today I have installed minGW-w64. As minGW it is in my `C:\` disk.

If I write in the VSC console `g++ --version` I can read:

```
g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC Build-20200227-1) 9.2.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO 
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

No mention of minGW-w64.

In the compiler I can choose it though...

[image]

I have created an environment variable for my user `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` in path, too.

Any ideas how to fix my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinGW / gcc: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124182/mingw-gcc-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b)

Comment: Whatever mingw you use to build: Its bin directory must be in the PATH variable (as set by the system control panel/advanced/environment variables) because the program must load dlls residing there which Windows searches for along the PATH.

Comment: I have created that environment variable (C:\msys64\mingw64\bin) in PATH both in the user and in the system.

Comment: As you notice yourself, that does not appear to be the compiler VSC uses to compile ;-).

Comment: HRESULT decoder [0xc000007b](https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0xc000007b).  For future reference.

Comment: what is the difference between user and system path variables?