# c++ compilation with mingw silently failing

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw

I'm trying to compile a .cpp file with MinGW. Here are my steps:

- I downloaded MinGW (latest release) and added "C:\MinGW\bin" to path
- I navigate to the folder with my .cpp and header files
- from there, I open windows powershell
- I run `g++ main.cpp`

This seemingly completes without errors but I don't see a new .exe file appearing.

I checked the g++ version to make sure it is available and it is --> `g++.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0`

I'm not sure what could be going wrong?

update:
tried running it from terminal instead of powershell which gives--> cc1plus.exe Application Error: the application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000279)
The same happens if I run terminal as administrator.
Still no change when I introduce an error into the code.

Update 2: Updated to version 12.1.0, and now we're back to silently failing with no error

Comment: Just a guess, file/folder permissions?

Comment: Experiment, try putting a deliberate error in your main.cpp, compile again and see if you see the error reported.

Comment: Do you have a file called `a.exe` or `a.out`? You didn't specify an output file name, I think a.exe is the default.

Comment: @john, no files that have .exe or .out endings in this directory

Comment: Did you download it from Sourceforge? The compiled binary there is still broken, as per half a year back.

Comment: Try to download from https://winlibs.com/ instead. In case that doesn't solve the problem then check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124182/mingw-gcc-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b

Answer (score 0):

GCC 6.3.0 is very old. Looks like you used an old MinGW download. Instead you should download and install MinGW-w64. You can get a standalone version from https://winlibs.com/ or install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) and install MinGW-w64 via the package manager `pacman`.

The https://winlibs.com/ option is the easiest, as it requires no installation, just extract to a folder and start using it.

I also recommend uninstalling the old MinGW from `C:\MinGW`, or at least make sure this folder doesn't appear anywhere in the `PATH` environment variable, as to not get the different versions' DLLs mixed up.