# MinGW c compiler not working (cc1.exe application error)

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, gnu, sublimetext4

I followed a step by step tutorial on how to code in c with sublime text 4 on windows 11.
I installed the mingw from sourceforge,in the installer I selected the basic mingw installation, the folder's path is "C:\MinGW", then I added the path of the bin folder to the environment path variable.
but when I use the build with tool in sublime text to compile a main.c file I get this error message

[image]

I tried reinstalling mingw and following the tutorial another time still the same problem

Comment: some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124182/mingw-gcc-the-application-was-unable-to-start-correctly-0xc000007b

Comment: Mingw and Ming64 aren't maintained any longer. Sourceforge links lead to incorrect, broken builds since many years back. You have to download a build from a less sucky place such as https://winlibs.com/.

Comment: I downloaded a build from the link you gave but when I checked it the include folder was missing a couple of file headers such as stdio.h I copy and pasted the missing headers from the old installation but when I try compiling a code it tells me there is a missing printf and scanf declarations even though I have "#include <stdio.h>" in the top of the code seems like the declarations are not being detected

Comment: @FaresAyadi You shouldn't mess around with that manually. In particular, copying just a header file will achieve nothing, since it doesn't contain the executable library code. Headers are just a public application programmer interface (API) to the actual library, which needs to be linked with your program or nothing will work.

Comment: As mentioned in the Winlibs link, Mingw can come with one out of two "C runtimes" (CRT) which is the code you need to run C on top of it, as well as the standard libs. Depending on which version you downloaded, it could either use the old Microsoft one, which I believe is partially already available as per Windows. Or the newer UCRT which is probably more up to date with the C standard. These are probably integrated in the build somehow, so what happens to sit in the `mingw-w64\include` top folder is irrelevant. Headers might be in some sub folder from there on but we don't need to care.

Comment: Just run a "hello world" program calling printf before jumping to conclusions of what was included in the build and what wasn't.

Comment: @Lundin Note that MinGW-w64 is definitely still supported, but distributed as source and to be combined with build tools (GCC/LLVM).
That is exactly why I started https://winlibs.com/ : to have an easy download that "just works".

Comment: @FaresAyadi There is a simple explanation on https://winlibs.com/#usage-commandprompt showing you how to build a simple "hello world" as Lundin suggested.

Comment: @BrechtSanders If it was still supported then at the very least they should withdraw the broken build sitting on Sourceforge. And stop referring to it as the official download link.